# GitLab CI: How to properly push file to a repo using ci file?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I'm trying to setup a GitLab CI pipeline which runs a script (`convert-inventory-format.sh`) that update a yaml file. I would then like to commit that file to a Git repository and push it.

However, the pipeline fails with the error:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The user provided works when trying this process outside of a CI pipeline

this is my gitlab-ci file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - update_yaml

build:
  tags:
    - gitlab-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - git submodule update --init --recursive

update_yaml:
  tags:
    - gitlab-runner
  stage: update_yaml
  script:
    - git branch
    - git checkout InventoriesWiki
    - git config user.email "XXX"
    - git config user.name "XXX"
    - chmod +x $CI_PROJECT_DIR/convert-inventory-format.sh
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/convert-inventory-format.sh
    - git add wiki_inventory.yaml
    - git commit -m "yay! new files!"
    - git push origin InventoriesWiki
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
    GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
    GIT_PUSH_OPTS: "--force"
    GIT_USER: XXX
    GIT_PASSWORD: XXX
```

i'm not sure why this pipeline fails, what is the best practice for running git commits in a gitlab ci pipeline?

I appericiate your help

I tried git ls-files and the file exists

Comment: It fails because there're no changes to commit and push. Run `git status` and `git diff` before `git add` to see the state of files after the main script.